# Word wrapping with RMagick and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

On my website I want the user to be able to enter several lines of text, and have it converted into an image.  My main problem is finding out the right equation for how many columns my picture has for font vs font size.

Here's my original code:

```
def create_image_from_text
    require 'RMagick'
    @event = Event.for_company(current_domain.company_id).find(params[:event_id])
    @lots = @event.lots
    lot_image = Magick::ImageList.new
    lot_image.new_image(590, 443)
    y = -200
    params[:rows].each do |row|
        if row[1][:text].present?
            text_tool = Magick::Draw.new

            text = row[1][:text]
            text_tool.pointsize = row[1][:size].to_f

            if row[1][:bold].present?
                text_tool.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
            end
            if row[1][:italic].present?
                text_tool.font_style = Magick::ItalicStyle
            end
            text_tool.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
            location = y
            columns = lot_image.columns / row[1][:size].to_f
            word_wrap(text, columns.to_i).split("\n").each do |row|
                text_tool.annotate(lot_image, 0, 0, 0, location += 20, row)
            end
            #text_tool.annotate(lot_image,0,0,0,y, text)
        end
        y += 80
    end
    lot_image.write('test.gif')
    render :new_image_from_text
end

def word_wrap(text, columns = 80)
    text.split("\n").collect do |line|
        line.length > columns ? line.gsub(/(.{1,#{columns}})(\s+|$)/, "\\1\n").strip : line
    end * "\n"
end
```

With how its set up it works, but the word wrapping is much too small.  I want the text to be spread out through out the whole 590 px length, instead it only spreads it out about half way.

Here is what it creates now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyC9c.jpg

Any ideas out there on a better equation?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to handle it?